# Android Displaying more than 1 variable textView

Tags: android, textview

I have a textView and I want to display two different variables at the same time, each on one line.
Here is what I have so far

```
TextView.setText("You answered :" + " " + correct + "correct" + '\n');
TextView.setText("You answered: " + " " + wrong + "incorrect");
```

this only displays the last line and not both lines of code in the textView. Can anyone tell me how i can go about displaying both of these in the same textView at the same time on 2 different lines? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String text = "You answered :" + " " + correct + "correct\n" +"You answered: " + " " + wrong + "incorrect";
TextView.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this snip code:

```
TextView.setText("You answered :" + " " + correct + "correct\n" +"You answered: " + " " + wrong + "incorrect");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**:

```
TextView.setText("You answered: " + correct + "correct\nYou answered: " + wrong + "incorrect");
```

Note: By convention, you should avoid naming variables with capital letters, especially if the name is already a class name. Consider using `textView` instead of `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try create the String first then set the text in the `TextView`.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't the generic answer:

```
TextView.setText("You answered :" + " " + correct + "correct" + '\n');
// Lots of other intervening code
TextView.append("You answered: " + " " + wrong + "incorrect");
```

In addition, there is a lot of unnecessary string operations:

```
TextView.setText("You answered : " + correct + "correct\n");
// Lots of other intervening code
TextView.append("You answered:  " + wrong + " incorrect");
```